# Increase font size of ion-input text

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, font-size

I am working on the Ionic 5 application for iPad/Tablet. I want to increase the font size of ion-input for full app.

I have tried various options

```
ion-input {
      font-size: 20px !important;
}

input {
      font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

But none of it is increasing the font size. I have even tried to increase the browser inspect element there also it has increased the space but font size is same.

My code structure is

```
<ion-item class="ion-padding-horizontal">
<ion-label class="input-label" position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
<ion-input class="input-text" type="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

When I give font size in the input-text class it is just increasing the size of the input, not the font size

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you input is in an ion-item element and then give it your class like this:

CSS:

```
.size {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input class="size"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I tested it just now. it works.

Comment: I have already tried this. I have added my code structure and output for this in question

Comment: @hardiksa remove other classes from your ion-input HTML and give it just font class. see if it works.

Comment: @hardiksa did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It worked. My classes and your class both have worked. It's the issue of saved username/password in chrome :(. As it is auto filed I didn't try by typing different text. Just noticed it now